# Adding url path to backend HAPROXY

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, haproxy

I want to add a path to url if only no path defined. E.g.

hostname:8080 -> then add /fe:   ->   hostname:8080/fe

The answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40488319/12501050 does not work:

```
acl p_root path -i /
http-request set-path /fe if p_root
```

as it blocks the other requests. E.g.

hostname:8080/fe/getUsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is little tricky to implement, but not that hard to work. Something like this works.

```
acl p_root path -i /
acl is_domain hdr(host) -i myhostname.io
redirect code 301 location myhostname.io/fe if is_domain p_root
```

Hope this is helps.